# How to modify UISwitchController so it ended up looking like this:

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode4.5, uiswitch

Basically I want to customize the background and the button. I want the button to be square. Things like that.

My designers already provide me with this pictures:

[image]
[image]

A thing I am looking into is to just use UIButton. However, how do I make UIButton to be on switch mode? What should I do so that if button is clicked then it becomes "selected"

The result that I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *switchButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[switchButton setBackgroundImage:offImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[switchButton setBackgroundImage:onImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

When you want the button to look "on", just do: `switchButton.selected = YES;` after it has been tapped or whenever else you want to set it to that state.

Answer (score 2):

This code may help Your query , you have to modify it ..

https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch

Thanks.